# Concatenate .txt files with same names in different folders with python

Tags: python, linux

I have two folders containing many text files with matching file names. So I am concatenating folder1/file1.txt with folder2.file1.txt. My current code appends data from folder2/file1 to folder2/file1 instead from two different folders.

```
import glob,os
path='/my/dir'
data = data2 = ""
#read files with only.txt extension
for filename in glob.glob('.txt'):
#open folder1/file1 for reading
   with open(path, filename,'r') as fp:
        data=fp.read()
        print(filename)
#open folder2/file1 for reading
   with open(os.path.join(path, "/output", filename, 'r')) as fp:
        data2=fp.read()
        data +="\n"
        data +=data2
#open output file for writing
   with open (filename,"-new",'.txt', w) as fp:
        fp.write(data)
```

For python 2.7 I modified the code like below

```
import glob,os,shutil
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
path='/My/dir'
outdir='/My/dir/merged'
fol1='/my/dir/input1'
fol2='/my/dir/input2'

def concat_files(dir1, dir2, outdir, ext='.txt'):
    assert len({dir1, dir2, outdir}) == 3, "all dirs must be different"
    os.makedirs(outdir)
    a = os.listdir(dir1)
    b = os.listdir(dir2)
    for item1 in a:
        for item2 in b:
            if(item1==item2):
               out = os.path.join(outdir, item1)
               with open(out, 'w') as fdst:
                   if item1 in a:
                      with open(os.path.join(dir1, item1), 'r') as fsrc:
                          shutil.copyfileobj(fsrc, fdst)
                   if item2 in b:
                      with open(os.path.join(dir2, item2), 'r') as fsrc:
                          shutil.copyfileobj(fsrc, fdst)
print("Your merged file is in " ,outdir)
concat_files(fol1, fol2, outdir)
```

Comment: can you provide some more info? Are there subfolders in `folder1` and `folder2`, or just flat list of files?  What should happen if a file is present in `folder1` but not in `folder2`, and vice-versa? Why append to files in `folder2` instead of creating a new merge folder (e.g. `folder3`)?

Comment: There are subfolders in folder 1 but no subfolders in folder2. But i am just interested in folder 1 and folder2 and not in any other subfolders. I am generating some other output too in folder 2 and its convenient to have everything in one folder

Answer (score 0):

The question does not specify what is desired to happen when a file is found in one of the two folders only. Below I assume we want all files, even if they are present in only one folder.

Anyway, taking my best guess at what is desired (happy to change if more details are forthcoming):

```
def ls_txt_files(path, ext='.txt'):
    """return a list of files under path as a set"""
    return {
        ent.name
        for ent in os.scandir(path)
        if ent.is_file() and ent.name.endswith(ext)
    }

def concat_files(dir1, dir2, outdir, ext='.txt'):
    assert len({dir1, dir2, outdir}) == 3, "all dirs must be different"
    os.makedirs(outdir, exist_ok=True)
    a = ls_txt_files(dir1, ext)
    b = ls_txt_files(dir2, ext)
    for name in a.union(b):
        out = os.path.join(outdir, name)
        with open(out, 'w') as fdst:
            if name in a:
                with open(os.path.join(dir1, name), 'r') as fsrc:
                    shutil.copyfileobj(fsrc, fdst)
            if name in b:
                with open(os.path.join(dir2, name), 'r') as fsrc:
                    shutil.copyfileobj(fsrc, fdst)
```

(**Updated** to reflect the comments by @ShadowRanger).

Comment: Minor improvement: Never use `os.listdir` + stat-ing operations in modern Python. Use `os.scandir` and let it do more work for you (and use native `set` comprehensions, not `set()` + genexpr): `return {ent.name for ent in os.scandir(path) if ent.is_file() and ent.name.endswith(ext)}`. That'll be shorter and faster than the alternative (aside from cases involving symlinks, it avoids the implicit `stat` from `os.path.isfile` by getting that information directly from the underlying directory listing function, reducing system calls from one for each file and directory, to just one per directory).

Comment: Also, your original code has a minor typo; you used `dir1` in `ls_txt_files`, when you only have access to `path` from your arguments.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: good eye! and yes, agreed, I remember reading that several `os` functions cache the `stat`. But I agree this is cleaner. The `set(generator)` is equivalent to `{generator}`, as far as I know: they both pass the comprehension expression as a generator to `set.__init__()`, isn't it?

Comment: The script runs without errors but doesn't perform any concatenation. Also if there is no file1 in dir2 then ignore concatenation.

Comment: @PierreD: Actually, `{generator}` doesn't make a true generator at all; `set` comprehensions build the `set` directly, have no concept of yielding control the way a real generator does (saving and restoring generator state has overhead the `set` comprehension avoids), and it uses dedicated bytecodes to do it (improving speed over solutions like a normal `for` loop that call `set.add` over and over). The dedicated `list`, `set` and `dict` comprehensions always outperform passing a generator expression to the associated type constructor. It mostly a microoptimization, but it costs nothing.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: you are right; I learned something new: 18% improvement on `i for i in islice(count(), 1_000_000)` as the genexpr.

Comment: @akang: what did you give as `outdir`? The merged files should be there. The dir is created if it doesn't exist yet, so try with e.g. `outdir='/tmp/foobar'` or anything you can later dispose of.

Comment: I did give a location for outdir. But it is not being created and no concatenation.

Comment: Operations such as `os.makedirs()` and `open(out, 'w')` are not going to fail silently... Either the code works, or you would get an exception (e.g. if you attempted to write to an area where you don't have write access). My best guess is that you can't find the output because it ends up at a different location than where you think it should be (e.g. if relative dir and your cwd is some other place). For the second time: what exactly _did_ you give for `outdir`?

Comment: outdir='/folder1/testout'. I saved the code in folder 1 as testcode.py and ran it as sudo python testcode.py

Comment: **don't run as root**, especially code copy/pasted from StackOverflow. Also, to be clear, your code is calling `concat_files`, right? If I were you, I would construct a simple test dir in some safe place (e.g. `/tmp/merge_test`), make 2 folders with some files in them, and test there. Also try to use a debugger if you haven't already. This will be my last comment on this post. Good luck.

Comment: @Pierre D thanks for the help. I modified the code and it works perfect now.