# Python speed up element in list

Tags: python, pandas

I have made a script where I check if a column's values from dataframe A exist in a columns of dataframe B. Here, dataframe A is named whole data, and dataframe B is named referrarls

```
users=set(whole_data['user_id'])
referees=set(referrals['referee_id'])
non_referees=set([x for x in users if x not in referees])
```

As you can see, I want a list of users (named non_referees) that contain users that are not referees, that's why I am checking for every user_id from whole_data if it exists in the set of referees.

Nonetheless, this is taking a massive amount of time, there are like 100K users and 4K referees. Is there a way to make this faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to consider:

```py
non_referees = set(whole_data['user_id'].unique()).difference(
    referrals['referee_id'].unique()
)
```

If you think there are few repeats in `referrals['referee_id']`, then you'll gain a smidgen of speed by avoiding `.unique()` for them.

**Speed**

Here are some experiments with a few closely related forms:

1. Case with lots of duplicated `referee_id`

   ```py
   n = 100_000
   whole_data = pd.DataFrame({
       'user_id': np.random.randint(0, n, n),
   })
   referrals = pd.DataFrame({
       'referee_id': np.random.randint(0, n, n),
   })
   ```

   Measurements:

   ```py
   %timeit non_referees = set(pd.unique(whole_data['user_id'])) - set(pd.unique(referrals['referee_id']))
   # 23.4 ms ± 53.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

   %timeit non_referees = set(whole_data['user_id'].unique()) - set(referrals['referee_id'].unique())
   # 23.3 ms ± 36 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

   %timeit non_referees = set(whole_data['user_id'].unique()).difference(set(referrals['referee_id'].unique()))
   # 23.3 ms ± 73.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

   # *** fastest
   %timeit non_referees = set(whole_data['user_id'].unique()).difference(referrals['referee_id'].unique())
   # 21.4 ms ± 74.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

   %timeit non_referees = set(whole_data['user_id'].unique()).difference(referrals['referee_id'])
   # 29.6 ms ± 21.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
   ```
2. Case with few duplicates in `referee_id`:

   ```py
   n = 100_000
   whole_data = pd.DataFrame({
       'user_id': np.random.randint(0, n, n),
   })
   referrals = pd.DataFrame({
       'referee_id': np.random.randint(0, 100*n, n),
   })
   ```

   Measurements:

   ```py
   %timeit non_referees = set(pd.unique(whole_data['user_id'])) - set(pd.unique(referrals['referee_id']))
   # 30.7 ms ± 61.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

   %timeit non_referees = set(whole_data['user_id'].unique()) - set(referrals['referee_id'].unique())
   # 30.7 ms ± 25.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

   %timeit non_referees = set(whole_data['user_id'].unique()).difference(set(referrals['referee_id'].unique()))
   # 30.6 ms ± 57.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

   %timeit non_referees = set(whole_data['user_id'].unique()).difference(referrals['referee_id'].unique())
   # 23.7 ms ± 37.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

   # *** fastest
   %timeit non_referees = set(whole_data['user_id'].unique()).difference(referrals['referee_id'])
   # 20.9 ms ± 54 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
   ```

Answer (score 3):

First, pandas can already give you the unique values of a series, which might be faster than building the set from the whole column.

Second, to build the set of non-referees, you can then use set operations:

```py
non_referees = users - referees
```

EDIT: As an additional note, if you build a set using the generator expression style, you don't need to build an intermediate list:

```py
# slow because it first builds a list and then turns that into a set:
some_set = set([x for x in something])

# faster because it goes right into building the set:
some_other_set = set(x for x in something_else)
```

Comment: About your 'EDIT': that's actually the other way around. But even faster is `{generator}`. In the words of @ShadowRanger in a comment to an [answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65136503/758174), rightly said: Actually, {generator} doesn't make a true generator at all; set comprehensions build the set directly (...), and it uses dedicated bytecodes to do it (improving speed over solutions like a normal for loop that call set.add over and over). The dedicated list, set and dict comprehensions always outperform passing a generator expression to the associated type constructor.

Comment: In other words: `{x for x in something}` is fastest. `set([x for x in something])` is next, and `set(x for x in something)` is slowest.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wouldn't have guessed that set() is so much slower than Series.unique(), so I did it with unique() and it took less than a second, while set() was going on for 5 mins and it didn't finish. Any ideas why?

Comment: I can't know for sure without looking at source code, but especially with these high-performance libraries like pandas and numpy it's much faster if you can keep "within the library" for as long as possible without "crossing the boundary" to the rest of python. Pandas' own `unique` will be highly optimized for dataframes, whereas `set` is general purpose and doesn't know anything special about dataframes, series, numpy arrays etc.